# const char passed to a function is not reflecting back

Tags: c, linux

I want to change the contents of a `constant-character-array`(`const array[64]`).
Below is my code.
My **Question** is, why does the constant character array doesn't change(not reflected back), when passed to the function as constant character pointer(`const char *append`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int function(char *d,const char *append)
{
 append = d; //changing the location of append.
 printf ("%s\n",append); //displays as sachintendulkar.
}

int main()
{
    char *d = NULL;
    const char append[]={'s','a','c','h','i','n'};
    d = calloc(sizeof(char),sizeof(append));
    strcpy(d,append);
    strcat(d,"tendulkar"); //appending
    function(d,append);
    printf ("%s\n",append); //Its displays as sachin instead of sachintendulkar???
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function arguments are passed by value, when you assign a new value to the pointer `append` inside `function()`, nothing happens that is noted outside the function.

It's not very clear what you're trying to do ... The point of constant data is, of course, that you're not supposed to change it.

Comment: Thanks. My question, i am passing a constant character array append[] to a function which now becomes const char *append which means that append can point to some other constant string which is in this case is 'd'. Why this change in append is not reflected back.

Comment: You are basically making append point to a different buffer but ONLY inside that function; on return whatever was outside the function isn't changed. You need a double pointer (char **append) to change the argument and have it be visible outside the function. Also, upvoted parent :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can change `function()` to return a `char *`, return the new value of `append` from `function()`, and in `main()` assign `append` to the return value of `function()`.  This, at any rate, is what I'd do, simply because keeping track of multiple levels of indirection makes my head hurt.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a coincidence that the names of the parameters are the same as the variables in main. There is no connection between the names.

Your function works the same as if it was

```
int function(char *x, const char *y)
{
 y = x; //changing the location of y.
 printf ("%s\n", y); //displays as sachintendulkar.
}
```

You wouldn't expect that function to change the values inside main.